# Does running a compiled C file in Ruby capture C's printf()?

Tags: c, ruby, windows, stdout

I'm on ruby-2.2.2 (on Windows, with MinGW and UnixUtils) and I am writing a script which will compile, run, and diff the output of a .c file, and I am running into an issue where I attempt to execute a recently compiled C source file.

The C file is simple:

```
#include <stdio.h
int main() {
   printf("hello world.");
   return 0;
}
```

In my ruby file, I am running from a class' internal method.

```
def makeAndTest(filename)
   # code which removes any pre-existing .exe file not included

   compileResult = `gcc -O3 -o %s %s.c` % [filename, filename]
   if (!$?.success?)
        return
   end

   fileCall = `.\%s.exe` % filename
   puts fileCall
end
```

The file compiles just fine, but the actual file call that I make gives no output. As a sanity check, I've run simple commands such as "ls," which and the output is printed out as expected by a system() call. However, a command like "echo 23132" doesn't work as expected -- in fact, Ruby just doesn't print anything for either the echo call or my executable.

I've tried using system(), %x(), and backticks to try these calls, but I can never seem to get any output. This had led me to believe that Ruby must be doing *something* with my files stdout, right? I can run "echo 23132" or executing my file from cmd just fine, but ruby seems to fail at this.

If I check $?.success? after each call, it seems that both calls failed (yet the simple ls call succeeds).

Has anyone a clue what could be going on here? How does Ruby treat the stdout of files which it runs? In my mind, Ruby be pretty able to run a compiled .exe, so  don't understand what could be going on here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As this isn't isolated to the C language, rather to any language that contains the same behaviour, there probably shouldn't be a [c] tag here. What happens if you throw a `\n` onto the end of that string?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I honestly didn't know to add the C tag or not but I decided to -- whoops. If I added a \n to the string, nothing much would have happened. Turns out, as Martin helped me notice, Ruby couldn't find the file specified, so I fixed the file path that I was using. Kind of embarrassing, but that was it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your calls are failing, try printing the output of stderr by redirecting it to stdout

```
output = `echo 12345 2>&1`
```

Comment: Adding the \r doesn't seem to add an effect, the calls still seem to fail. ($?.success? returns false, that is)

Comment: Directing it to standard error helped, actually. It turned out that the script couldn't find the file at all (I was doing something wrong in directing it along the correct file path). Thanks for your help.